# How to plot u(x,y) in polar system, MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I have function

[image]

and I have to draw a graph of this function for (x,y) lying in the area

[image]

in **Polar coordinate system**, where 'ro' is radius.

I found it many ways how to create a graph for one variable, but not for the two variables. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you have to solve it for `x` and `y respectively and then work out `rho` and `theta`.

Comment: x=rho*cos(theta) and y=rho*sin(theta). WHere theta ranges from 0 to 2pi. Now you can compute your arrays data points lets say rho=0.9 and theta going the whole way. This way you get 2 array for x,y these you must use to get your field u. (each element with each element so use bsxfun and your given definition of u). Now you have just to plot it e.g. using surf or imagesc. You must get a matrix!

Comment: The above is not a curve but a surface. Did you want `iso-lines` instead such as `u(x,y)=K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it transformation from Cartesian coordinate system to Polar coordinate system 'in hand' and then I made a graph like that:

```
rho = linspace(0,0.9,50);
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
[RHO,PHI] = meshgrid(rho,phi);
u = (-1+RHO.^2)./(-RHO.^2+2*RHO.*sin(PHI)-1);

figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
set(gcf,'Color',[1,1,1])
box on;

surf(RHO,PHI,u)

xlabel('\rho');
ylabel('\phi');
zlabel('u(\rho,\phi)');
```

What do you think? Correct?

[image]